# Use iPhone5 storyboard for iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, screen-resolution

So, we are not supporting iPad (like really create a storyboard for it and all) but we want to be able to load our current storyboard on it just in case some users might want to still download it on their iPads. What we have is an iPhone5 storyboard. When we load it to an iPad, a portion is cut off which makes sense because we should have an iPhone4 storyboard to display everything on iPad. But is there a way to just load our current iPhone5 storyboard on to an iPad without scaling it. Just let it fit in the screen? Or should we really make an iPhone4 storyboard?

Comment: The iPad can only show the iPhone 3.5 inch layout.

Comment: you can redesign the story board enabling size classes and auto layout. then it will work on all devices

Comment: @ZeMoon i see. that's what I thought but I was just hoping there's another way I could do. but thanks.

Comment: Yeah, as the people suggest, its best to create adaptive layouts. This way, you can support all kinds of screen sizes using the same storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You get what you with one action. Just set in the settings of your project that it is for `iPhone` only, then `iPad` users will be able to use it, however, content will be centered and made small, like in `iPhone 4`. But there is an option to `2x` that but it will looks ugly. But the best solution is to create adaptive `storyboard`